# R Error in Rsx_nc4_get_vara_double: NetCDF: HDF error Var

Tags: r, netcdf

I'm running R package ncdf in Mac. I ran it before without a hitch.
This time I get this error:

Error in Rsx_nc4_get_vara_double: NetCDF: HDF error
Var: precip  Ndims: 3   Start: 0,0,0 Count: 25568,9,40
Error in ncvar_get_inner(ncid2use, varid2use, nc$var[[li]]$missval, addOffset,  :
C function R_nc4_get_vara_double returned error

I'm quite new to R and appreciate it if someone can help me with that.

I checked my data and package and these two have got no problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.